# ngTable not working for two tables

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have created an application in angularJS using ng-Table, In the application I am using grouping feature of ng-Table, The application is working fine for single table which is shown in a sample as given below

**Single Table with grouping in a single Controller**

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/f32h8GEhuYRKrP85Oxow?p=preview)**

But the problem is that in my application I am using two tables within a single controller, when i tried to put two tables with grouping feature
 I am not getting the table displayed

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**Two Tables with grouping in a single Controller**

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/40J3aCYXGp3CBjgnRAms?p=preview)**

```
  <body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table ng-table="firstTableParams" class="table">
      <tbody ng-repeat="group in myData.$groups">
        <tr class="ng-table-group">
          <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
          <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
          <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


    <table ng-table="secondTableParams" class="table">
      <tbody ng-repeat="group in myAnotherData.$groups">
        <tr class="ng-table-group">
          <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
          <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
          <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
```

Comment: why in second plunk `ng-repeat` apply for `myData.$groups` ?

Comment: ngTable, had not heard of that, took a look, disappointing, why does everyone write this crap for bootstrap. So annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over `$groups`

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">
```

in second plunk ,it must be like,since you resolving data by `defer` ,each table process its own data

```
<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table ng-table="firstTableParams" class="table">
      <tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups"> //changed here
        <tr class="ng-table-group">
          <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
          <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
          <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


    <table ng-table="secondTableParams" class="table">
      <tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups"> //changed here
        <tr class="ng-table-group">
          <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in group.data">
          <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
          <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

> for first table controller use $data in ng-repeat for both table it will work

```
$scope.firstTableParams= [];
    $scope.data= data;
    $scope.firstTableParams= new ngTableParams({
       page: 1,           
       count: 10,         
     }, {
       total: $scope.data.length, 
       getData: function($defer, params) {
           var filters = params.filter();
            if (params.settings().$scope == null) {
                        params.settings().$scope = $scope;
                  }
           var tempDateFilter;
           var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                           $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                           $scope.data;
           if(filters) {

             orderedData = $filter('filter')(orderedData, filters); 
             filters.Date = tempDateFilter;
           }
           $scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
           params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
           $defer.resolve($scope.users);
       }
  })`
```

> for second table controller

```
$scope.secondTableParams= [];
    $scope.data1= data;
    $scope.secondTableParams= new ngTableParams({
       page: 1,           
       count: 10,         
     }, {
       total: $scope.data1.length, 
       getData: function($defer, params) {
           var filters = params.filter();
            if (params.settings().$scope == null) {
                        params.settings().$scope = $scope;
                  }
           var tempDateFilter;
           var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                           $filter('orderBy')($scope.data1, params.orderBy()) :
                           $scope.data1;
           if(filters) {

             orderedData = $filter('filter')(orderedData, filters); 
             filters.Date = tempDateFilter;
           }
           $scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
           params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
           $defer.resolve($scope.users);
       }
  })
```